# How do you take prove a probability function given 2 unknowns?

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables

I am trying to prove the probability density function that the below equals one.

$$ f(x) = (1 + \alpha x)/2 $$

Given: $$-1 < x < 1 $$
$$ -1<\alpha<1$$
 **These < are less than or equal to**

I have gotten this far:

$$ \int\left(\frac x2\right)dx+\int\frac{\alpha x^2}2 dx$$

Any suggestions on how to manipulate
$\alpha$?

Thank you.

EDIT:
I wanted to prove the function above is a "density function" which means taking the integral and showing that it  = 1. The problem itself states:

Let f(x)(stated above) for -1 < x < 1 and f(x) = 0 otherwise, where -1 < (\alpha) < 1. Show f(x) is a density.

Thank you again for helping and welcoming me to the community.

Comment: Welcome! 
Please explain what do you mean by: "I am trying to prove the probability density function that the below equals one". It is not very clear...

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}{{\rm e}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}$

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1}{1 + \alpha\,x \over 2}\,\Theta\pars{1 + \alpha\,x}\,{\rm d}x
&=
\left.{1 \over 2}\pars{x + {1 \over 2}\alpha\,x^{2}}
\Theta\pars{1 + \alpha\,x}\right\vert_{-1}^{1}
\\[3mm]&-
\\[3mm]&
{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\pars{x + {1 \over 2}\alpha\,x^{2}}
\delta\pars{x + {1 \over \alpha}}{\rm sgn}\pars{\alpha}\,{\rm d}x
\end{align}

The right hand side integral vanishes out since
$\ds{{1 \over \verts{\alpha}} > 1}$. Then,
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1}{1 + \alpha\,x \over 2}\,\Theta\pars{1 + \alpha\,x}\,{\rm d}x
&=
{1 \over 2}\pars{1 + {1 \over 2}\alpha}\Theta\pars{1 + \alpha}
-
{1 \over 2}\pars{-1 + {1 \over 2}\alpha}\Theta\pars{1 - \alpha}
\end{align}
Notice that $1 \pm \alpha > 0$:
\begin{align}
\color{#ff0000}{\large%
\int_{-1}^{1}{1 + \alpha\,x \over 2}\,\Theta\pars{1 + \alpha\,x}\,{\rm d}x}
&=
{1 \over 2}\pars{1 + {1 \over 2}\alpha}
-
{1 \over 2}\pars{-1 + {1 \over 2}\alpha}
=
\color{#ff0000}{\Large 1}
\end{align}